# C# Streamreader add new line

Tags: c#, line, addition, streamreader

I have searched for this but every solution I've come across involves `regex` witch is not a solution for me.

My question is simple, I want the `streamreader` to add a new line everytime it reads the word "ice". Keep in mind that the `streamreader` is reading the input as 1 line.

My code is as follow:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    VarrileKeeper.s = sr.ReadToEnd();
    //Console.WriteLine(VarrileKeeper.s);
    if (VarrileKeeper.s.ToString().Contains("ice"))
    {
        //insert newline in string
    }
    sr.Close();
}
```

Comment: what about the word _iceland_ or something else containig the characters _ice_ ?

Comment: Do you want to *update* the file or just *read* it in such a manner?

Comment: Can't you just use `Replace`? `VarrileKeeper.s = sr.ReadToEnd().Replace("ice", "ice" + Environment.NewLine);`

Comment: `I want the streamreader to add a new line everytime it reads the word "ice"` - to *what* do you want the stream reader to add a line? to itself? it is a reader: it can only read. Note: your code currently just checked whether "ice" exists *at all*, not "every time"

Comment: Sorry, the string can look like this for example:

"283yrc2rc!"#54t45tice!"#!"#12iweumf83ficeice!"#!"#werweice"

Pretty much random string.

Comment: @Taco2 and what would your expected output look like? It would be best to edit your intended input and output into the question, using 4 spaces to indent it - then we'll be able to read them properly

Comment: I cannot edit the input stream.

Of course I cannot add a new line to the reader, but you got the poing I think.

Comment: Well... that's the thing; I *don't*; if you can't edit the input or the reader, where do you want these newlines to go?

Comment: @Muhammad Qasim thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Taco2 - you are welcome bro :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your question is exceedingly simple (or you haven't explained the complexities behind your problem).

I'd rather use System.IO.File and String.Replace to solve your problem:

```
string filename = "D:\\test.txt";
string output = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename).Replace("ice", "ice\n");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename, output);
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: Great answer but can it be done without using .txt and still keep it on a string?

Comment: @PatrickHofman to be fair, it can be trivially fixed: `.Replace("ice", "ice\n")` (or whatever definition of newline pleases you)

Answer (score 1):

Something with string.Split and string.Join could reach your goal

```
string temp = File.ReadAllText("yourfilename");
var parts = temp.Split(new string[] {"ice"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
VarrileKeeper.s = string.Join("ice"+ Environment.NewLine, parts);
```

but remember that this is indiscriminate on the character sequence *ice*, meaning that also more complex words will be truncated (venice for example.)

Comment: I can't understand people upvoting a wrong answer while leaving the actual answer sitting at 0... You have my vote Steve.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
 {
     {
         VarrileKeeper.s = sr.ReadToEnd();
         //Console.WriteLine(VarrileKeeper.s);
          if (VarrileKeeper.s.ToString().Contains("ice"))
          {
              VarrileKeeper.s = VarrileKeeper.s.Replace("ice", "ice" + System.Environment.NewLine);
          }

          sr.Close();
      }
}
```

Comment: That will only add line ends at the end.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
VarrileKeeper.s = string.Join(string.Empty, varrileKeeper.s.Split(' ').Select(x => x == "ice" ? x += Environment.NewLine : x += " "));
```

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: Replaces VarrileKeeper.s with new version containings new line after each "ice" word.